# Jquery .on click not working on first click

Tags: jquery, forms, click

I have a text field that I need to set the value for when a user either chooses an option from a select field or enters text in a text field and hits a link. Both events then close the div that contains the select and text field/link.

The select option works

```
$(document).on("change", ".select_choice", function(event) {
    var string = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find(".toggle_choices").toggle();
    $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find(".target_input").val(string);
});
```

The text field/link works on the second click. Any time something is entered into the field the link doesn't work on the first click. It hides the div, but doesn't update the value of the target field.

```
$(document).on("click", ".text_choice_button", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var string = $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find(".text_choice").val();
    $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find(".target_input").val(string);
    $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find(".toggle_choices").toggle();
});
```

Comment: is your "string" variable valid on first click?

Comment: If it toggles the div like you've said, then the event is firing, which suggests that `var string` isn't getting the correct value or you're not finding the `target_input`, try debugging with `console.log`

Comment: It does not appear that the variable is valid on the first click. I set an alert with the string variable right after the declaration and it comes up blank on first click, but on the second click comes up with the correct value.

Comment: find("text_choice") ...wrong selector? its probably a class..so it should change to find(".text_choice")

Comment: but surely it would never get the value if that were the case?

Comment: Yes that was a typo. It is correct in the code and I corrected it above. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Seems odd, could you post the markup as well, or better still, create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link.  http://jsfiddle.net/HHvKk/
Works in jsfiddle. So let me know if there's any other info needed. The html is a stripped down version of what's on the site. I removed stuff like classes used just for styling, dynamic elements such as the options for the select field and bootstrap divs used for positioning.

Answer (score 2):

### Unable to replicate

I have fiddled with this and am unable to replicate it: http://jsfiddle.net/DCM48/

Please upload a full fiddle with the issue for further help.

-Lededje

Answer (score 1):

try using delegate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").delegate("click", ".text_choice_button", function() {
           your code......
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with 'onclick' handler usign jquery. i find mousedown a more reliable solution.
Kind of catch the clicks better i find. http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score 0):

I always use this pattern, maybe you should try it too.

```
$(element).click(function() {});
```

Also post here html code you use javascript for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("body").click("a, div", function(){
        $("body").append("ping");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

try it with "live"

```
$(".text_choice_button").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var string = $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find("text_choice").val();
    $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find(".target_input").val(string);
    $(this).closest(".select_toggle_area").find(".toggle_choices").toggle();
});
```

Comment: And it does the exact same thing as the code provided in the question, only less efficient.